Uniform metric implies homeomorphic to $3$-sphere?
Perelman's proof for the Poincaré conjecture in dimension 3 roughly went as follows:  Deform the metric by Ricci flow and resolve singularity with surgery, forcing the metric of a simply connected 3-manifold to become increasingly "uniform".
But in the final step, how do we argue that a 3-manifold with a sufficiently uniform metric must be homeomorphic to the $3$-sphere?

Most introductory differential geometry textbooks have a section where simply-connected constant curvature manifolds are classified.  This and the theory of covering spaces, which you find in an introductory algebraic topology class, does the job.

The answers seem to interpret "sufficiently uniform" as "with constant sectional curvature". Is this really the intended assumption?

I understand that I did not well specify the question. But this is what's been circulating among none geometers. The last step, which I find  none obvious, turned out to be a basic undergraduate-level fact. I'm fine with having this question closed, but I believe it's useful for a big enough audience. It would be nice if someone could clarify it further, for example, whether Perleman's method always lead to constant sectional curvature, and whether it fails in dimension 4 because Ricci curvature fails to control sectional curvature.. etc.

@Student: I suggest you read about Thurston’s geometrisation conjecture, which is the full statement that Perelman proved. Thurston classifies 8 model geometries on 3-manifolds, only 3 of which have constant sectional curvature. Simply connectedness is only used right at the end of the proof, by noting that spherical geometry is the only one of the 8 that is compact. There cannot be an analogue of geometrisation in dimension 4.

I think "sufficiently uniform" in the context of your question should be replaced with "sufficiently small positive pinching constant". Then the claim follows from the sphere theorem.

This question seems to actually be about Hamilton's original paper https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214436922, which showed that a closed simply-connected 3-manifold of positive Ricci curvature is diffeomorphic to the 3-sphere. The proof is to deform any such metric by Ricci flow to a metric with constant positive curvature; then Student's answer applies.

It should also be pointed out that Perelman's proof doesn't actually make the metric on a closed simply-connected 3-manifold more uniform. Instead it will generally change the manifold itself and, in particular, doesn't generally homogenize the metric.

As Ryan Budney pointed out in the comment, this is due to a basic fact in Riemannian geometry. The following is quoted from [1, Theorem 8.4.1].
Let $M^{n}$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with constant sectional curvature $K$. Then the universal covering of $M$, with the covering metric, is isometric to

a) $H^{n}$, if $K = -1$,
b) $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, if $K =  0$,
c) $S^{n}$, if $K = +1$,

Reference

[1] Riemannian Geometry, by do Carmo.


It is unclear what "this" refers to (because the phrase "sufficiently uniform" has not been defined).
